# Decrement function, decrement all the rows in the tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

Im using laravel v3.2.12-4, and I have an problem with the decrement function. Instead of update only one row, this method affects all the rows in the column. Im using Eloquent, and I have a many_to_many relationship.

The code that constains the decrement method is:

```
 foreach ($ids as $id) {
 $indicator = Indicator::find($id);
 $tags = $indicator->tags()->get();
 foreach ($tags as $tag) {

    $indicator->tags()->detach($tag->id);
    if ($tag->frequency == 1) {
        $tag->delete();
    } else {
        // I have to made  this code to fix the problem with decrement function
        // But i want to use decrement
        $tag->frequency = $tag->frequency - 1;
        $tag->save();

        // This dosnt work for me.
        // $tag->decrement('frequency');
    }
}

$indicator->delete();

}
```

In the model class Indicator i made the relation with this function:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Tag');
}
```

In the model class Tag i made the relation with this function:

```
public function indicators()
{
    return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Indicator');
}
```

Well, if I made an update to the column this result OK for me, but when If I use the decrement function this affect all the rows and I don't know if this a bug or something with this method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it's designed. The `decrement()` method is actually [defined on the Query Builder](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/query.php#L861) and not on Eloquents builder. What this means is that when you call `$tag->decrement('frequency')` it's actually falling through to the QB and simply running a query like `UPDATE tag SET frequency=frequency - 1`. Notice that there's no WHERE clause?

You could still use the `decrement()` method but you'd have to do it like this.

```
$tag->where_id($tag->id)->decrement('frequency');
```

Now you've set the WHERE clause and only that tag will be decremented. Of course, the cleaner solution is what you've got. Or perhaps this.

```
$tag->frequency--;
```

Not tested, may throw an error of some sort.